# What is this part of the well pump/tank called, and how can I fix it?

Tags: pump, well

I just replaced the pressure switch on a home water system.  I primed the pump and pressure built up and water came out.  Water was dirty at first but it was clearing up (it hadn't been run for a while).  Pressure built up to 50 psi and cut off.  Ran the water and it cut back on.  Seemed to be working good, then it started leaking from a plastic bowl near the bottom of the vertical tank.  There's a pressure line (like that goes to the pressure switch) that goes from the pump to the "bowl".  I've seen similar things on home fuel oil tanks, but I don't know what it is called.  Kind of hard to fix it if you don't know what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, this is a horizontal tank.  The "bowl" is the end at the bottom.

Comment: There are many variations of jet pump configurations (at least I assume this is a jet pump, since you had to prime it), and I am really unsure from your description what part you're talking about. Can you take a picture and point out exactly where the leak is coming from (at least as best as you can identify)?